# Display views side by side

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am very new to MVC hence maybe its a basic problem.

I have created a controller called HomeController which would have a view displaying a navigation panel which behaves like a menu but should always be visible as the folders in Windows Explorer. On clicking on an item, I want to load another view to the right hand side (similar to master detail). Each item has a view and a model. To load the navigation panel I have the following code

```
        @foreach (var service in Model.Services)
        {
            @Html.ActionLink(service.Label, "Details", new { serviceName = service.ServiceName })

        }
```

This code works fine but is code opens another view and my navigation list disappears. Please guide how to open my Details view along with the Home view

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ajax to do this.

Split your page into 2 parts. The left - link container div and right preview div. When you click on a link, using ajax to call that link and update the DOM (preview div) of the same page.

```
<div>
  <div class="pageLeftMenuContainer">
      @foreach (var service in Model.Services)
      {          
        @Html.ActionLink(service.Label, "Details",
              new { serviceName = service.ServiceName },new { @class="ajaxLink"})
      }
  </div>
  <div class="pageRight" id="preview"></div>
</div>
```

Now listen to the click event on the links with the css class ajax link and load the preview div. You can use jquery load() method.

```
$(function(){
   $(".ajaxLink").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault(); // prevent the normal link click behavior
     $("#preview").load($(this).attr("href"));
   });
});
```

Comment: Little lost. I have 'Details' action in my HomeController. Where do I put the code '$function....'?

Comment: You have to include that js code in the view (inside a script section) where you have the menu links.

Comment: This still opens a new window and my navigation panel disappears